# how to set default all hotkey in mac

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I want to return default all keyboard hotkey

Now my mac

`command + w` is `Screen Brightness up`

`command + e` is `Screen Brightness down`

but i want to `command + w` is `close this app` (default)

can anyone help me?

**My karabiner**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You obviously mean: How do I do this with Karabiner Elements … ?!?

For one: `"Cmd-W"` *is not default* for closing apps, but `"Cmd-Q"` is.

But, if you *really* want `"Cmd-W"` to close an app, here is Karabiner Elements' code:

```
{ "title": "Make ''Cmd-W'' close the current app.",
  "rules": [
     { "description": "Makes ''Cmd-W'' the shortcut for closing apps.",
       "manipulators": [
        { "from": { "key_code": "w",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "mandatory": ["left_command"] }
                  },
            "to":[
                 { "key_code": "q",
                   "modifiers": ["left_command"],
                   "repeat": false }],
          "type":  "basic"
                }  
            ]
        }
    ]    
}
```

Copy code to BBEdit (TextEdit) and save to `~/.config./karabiner/assets/complex_modifications` as `WhateverYouLike.json`

Next open KE, tab "Complex Modifications", click `[+ Add rule]` at bottom, scroll down to `WhateverYouLike.json` and click `[+ Enable]`.

That should be it … KE's modifications work without restart.

*(Btw: the "repeat" part makes your shortcut close only ONE app, just to make sure …)*